# Story in which future writing is described as being about worlds instead of characters

Tags: story-identification

I remember one detail from a short story/novel. It said (paraphrasing):

> in the future, writing will be about worlds and societies instead of characters

I'm not sure about the wording (including tense) but I think the sense was that it would be just a description of a static fictional world (reminiscent of a form of worldbuilding), not a large-scale narrative.

I think there was some type of AI or sentient robots. I don't know how the future prediction is known, or if it's the future relative to the present or to the setting of the story.